# generate array of merged cells handsontable

Tags: javascript, arrays, merge, handsontable

for example i have an array of rows:

```
{ "name1", "value1", "other1", "another1" },
{ "name1", "value2", "other2", "another2" },
{ "name2", "value3", "other3", "another3" },
{ "name2", "value4", "other4", "another4" }
```

i cant generate the array that will have the structure of merged cells like:

```
{ row: 0, col: 0, colspan: 1, rowspan: 2 }, 
{ row: 2, col: 0, colspan: 1, rowspan: 2 }
```

where **row** is row index, **col** column index, **colspan** is span of columns and **rowspan** is the span of rows on table.

so far i have the code:

```
var prev;
var entry = {};
var repeat = 1;
var result = [];
for(a in data){ 
  if(a>0){
    prev = data[a-1];
    for(b in data[a]){
      if(prev[b]===data[a][b]){
         if(repeat==1){
            entry["row"] = a-1;
            entry["col"] = b;
            entry["colspan"] = 1; 
         }
         repeat++;
      } 
    }
  }
}
```

but i cant understand when i can make `rowspan=repeat` then make `repeat=1`, again and at the same time i need to push this `entry` inside the `result`

thank you all for the help!

**EDIT:** I've managed to do almost working example, but with little mistake, it doesnt push the last merge... any ideas to make it push the last entry?!

```
var cols = data[0].length;
var prev;
var entry = {};
var repeat = [];
for(var i=0;i<cols;i++){
  repeat.push(1);
}
var result = [];
for(a in data){
  if(a>0){
    prev = data[a-1];
    for(b in data[a]){
      if(prev[b]!=null&&prev[b]===data[a][b]){
        if(repeat[b]==1){
          entry["row"] = a-1;
          entry["col"] = parseInt(b);
          entry["colspan"] = 1;
        }
        repeat[b]++;
      }else{
        if(repeat[b]>1){
          entry["rowspan"] = repeat[b];
          result.push(entry);
          repeat[b] = 1;
          entry = {};
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

it is clear that my structure has a minus in that it is using the prev variable and starts from second row... but i didnt come up with any other better way.

Comment: Is `{ "name1", "value1", "other1", "another1" }`  supposed to be an array?

Comment: @Redu it doesnt matter, it can be object or array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i figured out how i can do it :) here is my code, just in case if someone will need it. Not the best way thou... but it works!

```
var cols = data[0].length;
var prev;
var entry = {};
var repeat = [];
for(var i=0;i<cols;i++){
  repeat.push(1);
}
var result = [];
for(a in data){
  if(a>0){
    prev = data[a-1];
    for(b in data[a]){
      if(prev[b]!=null&&prev[b]===data[a][b]){
        if(repeat[b]==1){
          entry["row"] = a-1;
          entry["col"] = parseInt(b);
          entry["colspan"] = 1;
        }
        repeat[b]++;
      }else{
        if(repeat[b]>1){
          entry["rowspan"] = repeat[b];
          result.push(entry);
          repeat[b] = 1;
          entry = {};
        }
      }
    }
    if(a==data.length-1){
      for(var i=0;i<repeat.length;i++){
        if(repeat[i]>1){
          entry["rowspan"] = repeat[i];
          result.push(entry);
          repeat[i] = 1;
          entry = {};
        }
      }  
    }
  }
}
```